# Can't find some data on Mongos while it's exists on shard

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 Mongos instances and 6 Mongod instances behind it. There are 2 auto-sharding shard and each one has 3 replica-set.

Today I find that I can't find some data on my system, but I can find it on RockMongo. I try to find it on mongos but nothing can be found. But the result of count() told me the data is still there.

```
mongos> db.video.find({ _id: ObjectId('51a0e7625c8e87cc6a000027') })
mongos> db.video.count({ _id: ObjectId('51a0e7625c8e87cc6a000027') })
1
mongos> db.runCommand({ count: "video", query: { _id: ObjectId('51a0e7625c8e87cc6a000027') } })
{ "shards" : { "s1" : 0, "s2" : 1 }, "n" : 1, "ok" : 1 }
```

I connect to shard2 and find the record, but many fields was lost. Meanwhile, the record shows up in RockMongo had all fields.

```
shard2:PRIMARY> db.video.find({ _id: ObjectId('51a0e7625c8e87cc6a000027') })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a0e7625c8e87cc6a000027"), "comment" : 78, "like" : 142, "scores" : { "total" : 37042292210.73388, "popular" : 72980.66026813157, "total_play" : 8737, "week_play" : 71 }, "views" : 8739 }
```

Then I found that the data count shows up in RockMongo was 24w+, but the result return by running db.xx.count() on mongos was 23w+. Some data lost on Mongos!

I have tried dump the collection and restore to another server and everything is ok. There must be some thing between mongos and mongod, what should I do now?

Comment: Just to clarify, you querying the same document over mongos, and directly on the appropriate shard which holds it. Is that the exact experiance that from mongos for the same document you see different fields than from the query on the shard? (Can you please provide the document which is the result from the query running on mongos?)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found that the primary of shard2 lost some data, but else replica sets of shard2 keep full data. I shutdown primary and create a new replica set. Everything is fine now.